# I want to remove Steam completely but I accidentley removed Steam uninstaller

Tags: steam

I recently tried to remove Steam so I manually started deleting files, including Steam uninstaller. There are a few files that can not be deleted because they're open in Steam, however I exited Steam already.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing it and then uninstalling it again?

Comment: have you checked the list of running processes? you can see if it still is running, and you can stop it from there.

Comment: Recycle Bin not have the uninstaller in it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Steam installed on Windows:

Open the Task Manager:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and then click on the "Task Manager" Button.

[image]

In the Processes Tab (should look like on the Screenshots) look for processes which have to do with Steam:

These are typically:

- Steam Client WebHelper
- Steam Client Bootstrapper
- Steam Client Service

End those.

Answer (score 1):

Although you may not see steam running in your task bar, it may still be running in the background which would prevent these files from uninstalling. If you are using Windows press CTRL+SHIFT+ESC to open your task manager. From here select processes and sort by image name. Scroll down until you see "steam.exe" or something similar. Left click it and press End Process in the bottom right corner, then attempt to uninstall steam completely. If this does not work a computer restart should also solve this problem.